# Too much space at the top of a beamer block when using multilined math environment

Tags: beamer, spacing, equations

I would like to place two math lines in a `beamer` block, as two separately 
centered lines.

I know that I could do this using two distinct equation environments, but it would be nicer to use a single environment like `gather`, or `align` (though align is not exactly what I want). When I do this (with `gather`), an ugly space appears at the top of the block, before the first equation. See below. How can I get rid of this space while still using gather or align (perhaps I should be using another environment altogether?)

```
\begin{block}{Separation of variables}
\begin{equation*}
\eps u'''' - (yu')' = \lambda u,
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
u''(0)=u'''(0)=0 \quad \text{(Free),} \qquad u(1)=u''(1)=0 \quad\text{(Clamped)}
\end{equation*}
\end{block}
\begin{block}{Separation of variables}
\begin{gather*}
\eps u'''' - (yu')' = \lambda u,\\
u''(0)=u'''(0)=0 \quad \text{(Free),} \qquad u(1)=u''(1)=0 \quad\text{(Clamped)}
\end{gather*}
\end{block}
```

Gives me: 
[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can set the length `abovedisplayskip` to `0pt` (or any other desired value):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{block}{Separation of variables}
\begin{gather*}
 u'''' - (yu')' = \lambda u,\\
u''(0)=u'''(0)=0 \quad \text{(Free),} \qquad u(1)=u''(1)=0 \quad\text{(Clamped)}
\end{gather*}
\end{block}
\begin{block}{Separation of variables}
\setlength\abovedisplayskip{0pt}
\begin{gather*}
 u'''' - (yu')' = \lambda u,\\
u''(0)=u'''(0)=0 \quad \text{(Free),} \qquad u(1)=u''(1)=0 \quad\text{(Clamped)}
\end{gather*}
\end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Of course, you can use something like

```
\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{\setlength\abovedisplayskip{0pt}}
```

right after `\begin{document}` to apply the change to all the blocks.

[image]

Comment: Does it make sense that \abovedisplayskip is used in a gather but not in an equation?

Comment: Do I really have to write this command at every frame? is there a global setting I could use? Is this a beamer thing or a latex thing?

Comment: @Yossi Farjoun: `\abovedisplayskip` and friends are  defined in files like `size10.clo`,or `size12.clo`, depending on the font size, so you cannot change their value in the preamble using a simple `\setlength`. However, you can use something like this in the preamble: `\AtBeginDocument{\setlength\abovedisplayskip{0pt}}`

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: This would eliminate the space between a paragraph and a displayed equation following it, though, wouldn't it? Seems like what we'd want is for `\abovedisplayskip` to be zero *only at the start of a Beamer block*.

Comment: @LukeMaurer: yes. I've added to my answer the code to apply the change only to the blocks.

Comment: It may also be advisable to adjust `\belowdisplayskip`, as well as `\afterdisplayshortskip` and `belowdisplayshortskip`.

Comment: \setlength\above...\below...does not work at all.

Comment: Very useful to "correct" a similar behaviour with `align*`. Is there a way to put the `\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{\setlength\abovedisplayskip{0pt}}` command directly inside the preambule ?

Answer (score 4):

A crude, but simple way is to insert `\vspace{-.5cm}` (or whatever *negative* distance suits you) just before starting the `gather` environment.
Most likely someone knows a better way than this quick-and-dirty workaroumd... :)