# Block environment with empty title in Beamer: how to reduce empty space at the top

Tags: beamer, spacing, align

I'm using the LaTeX `beamer` class to write a presentation. I'm placing vertically aligned equations inside a block environment without a title. When I do this, I get extra empty space at the top of the resulting block, before the first equation begins. Here is a minimal working example (MWE) that illustrates my problem

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{
\usetheme[secheader]{Boadilla}
}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{block}{}
\begin{align*}
Eq1&=0\\
Eq2&=0
\end{align*}
\end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With the above code there's more empty space before the first equation than there is after the last one. Is there a way of vertically centering the aligned equations inside the block so that there is an equal amount of empty block space left above and below the equations? Moreover, can one specify exactly how much empty space? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: I'm using the Boadilla theme, but I changed the outer color theme from "dolphin" to "beaver" (I don't know what MWE stands for, but hopefully this extra info helps?). I don't think the question is a duplicate of the one you linked, because I already know how to produce a block environment without title. My question is about the vertical alignment of equations inside the title-less block that I already have.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments. I have now edited my question by adding a MWE.

Comment: This is due the `align` environment. Duplicate: [Too much space at the top of a beamer block when using multilined math environment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28251). Also related: [Spurious space above align environment at top of page/minipage](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36954)