# Beamer Block: White Space When Using Math

Tags: beamer, math-mode, spacing

I want to reduce the white space (above and below) when I insert an equation environment in a beamer block.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Antibes}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{block}{Separation of variables}
\setlength\abovedisplayskip{0pt}
\begin{equation}
1 + 2 = 3
\end{equation}
\end{block}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I searched the web of course but the solutions I found do not seem to work (like `\setlength\abovedisplayskip{0pt}`).

What I found and should have worked:

- [One](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28251/too-much-space-at-the-top-of-a-beamer-block-when-using-multilined-math-environme)
- [Two](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69662/how-to-globally-change-the-spacing-around-equations#)

Comment: Do you mean the whitespace around the equation nside the block, or the whitespace around the whole block?

Comment: I updated the picture :)

Comment: Thanks Steven. egreg's answer explained the paragraph problem. I was just wondering why the abovedisplayskip parameter had no effect.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A displayed equation should never be at the top of anything. The problem is that a paragraph is started and then the equation is typeset.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Antibes}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{block}{Separation of variables}
\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\setlength\belowdisplayshortskip{0pt}
\begin{equation}
1 + 2 = 3
\end{equation}
\end{block}

\begin{block}{Separation of variables}
Some text
\end{block}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @jotagah A `block` like the second one would be printed incorrectly.

Comment: We can also to use \addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\setlength\belowdisplayshortskip{0pt}} ?

Comment: Egreg, l understand now the picture.

Comment: Worked like a charm. one before \[ and one before \]...do you mind explaining difference between \vspace and \vspace* ?

Comment: @TroyWoo `\vspace*` inserts a vertical space that's not removed at page breaks. In this case probably `\vspace` would be good as well.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I feel that somehow lack a systematic education of latex. I wonder how everyone else picked it up...by reading the tex book??!

Comment: @TroyWoo There are many possible roads; a well written LaTeX guide is a good starting point. Look at http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latexresources.html