# First line in beamer block ignores abovedisplayskip?

Tags: beamer, spacing, amsmath

If I use an an `align` environment within the a beamer block, the `\abovedisplayskip` is ignored. How can I force that setting?

My MWE is

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\usecolortheme{rose}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\abovedisplayskip=0pt
\begin{frame}
\begin{block}{Some Block}
\begin{align} %does not have 0pt abovedisplayskip
    e^x &= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!}
\end{align}
\end{block}
\begin{block}{Some other Block}
text
\begin{align} %abovedisplayskip works after text line
    e &= \lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1+\frac1n\right)^n
\end{align}
\end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: A display at the start of a paragraph forces a line before it.

Comment: To suppress the space above do `\nointerlineskip\begin{align}`. But there will still be space after. And this is not nice with the beamer background color.

Comment: ...but `\belowdisplayskip=0pt` will get rid of it.

Comment: thanks, that solves my problem at least locally. Is there a way to suppress this additional line globally for all displays? I will just add `\nointerlineskip` to the block definition. Apparently `beamer` does that for the frametitle already.

Comment: potential duplicate: [Beamer Block: White Space When Using Math](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/172602/579)