# Extra space between title and content with mdframed

Tags: spacing, mdframed

I have created a "solution" environment for some lecture notes, and I am experiencing an unexplainable space between the word Solution, which is the title of an mdframed environment and the beginning of the solution, when I starts with a formula. My solution sometimes start with a formula and other with a sentence, so I cannot simply add a negative `\vspace` to solve the problem. Herewith an example: sorry if it is a bit long.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\mdfdefinestyle{ExampleStyle}{%
    skipabove=\topskip,
    skipbelow=\topskip,
    innerbottommargin=2ex,
    linewidth=1pt,
    leftline=false,
    rightline=false,
    frametitlefont={\color{DarkBlue}\normalfont\bfseries},
    frametitlerule=false,
    frametitlebackgroundcolor=White,
    backgroundcolor=White,
    linecolor=DarkBlue}

\mdfdefinestyle{SolutionStyle}{%
    skipabove=\topskip,
    skipbelow=\topskip,
    topline=false,
    roundcorner=10pt,
    frametitlefont={\color{DarkBlue}\normalfont\bfseries},
    frametitle={Solution},
    frametitlerule=true,
    frametitlebackgroundcolor=DarkBlue!10,
    backgroundcolor=DarkBlue!10,
    linecolor=DarkBlue!10,
    fontcolor=DarkBlue}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}  

\mdtheorem[style=ExampleStyle]{Example}{Example}[section]
\newmdenv[style=SolutionStyle]{Solution}

\begin{document}

\begin{Example}
Work out~$2 + 3\times 5$.
\end{Example}

\begin{Solution}
\[
\begin{split}
2 + 3\times 5 &= 2 + 15 \cr
&= 17
\end{split}
\]
\end{Solution}
\end{document}
```

The outcome is the following:

[image]

Comment: Waiting for a MWE `:-)` I know of a very similar problem in `beamer`: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/172602/82917. I don't use `mdframed` a lot but I guess it's a similar issue.

Comment: Thank you! You are actually right, but I have, let's say, a hundred examples and I really wish I could do it automatically. Is there any chance to be able to make the space adjustment automatic, somehow?

Comment: You have "ExampleStyle" and "SolutionStyle". Could you not just modify "SolutionStyle"?

Comment: That's mainly because of `split` environment. If you use textual sentences, then I don't think it will render more space.

Comment: Yup, but I often use `split` in that context because I am solving little expressions, derivatives, integrals. So I really hope I can make it work somehow.