# Align content top with beamer (and metropolis)

Tags: beamer, vertical-alignment

I'm having trouble aligning content top with Beamer even when I add the class option `t`. Ideally, I would like my content to be flushed to the same vertical height irrespective of what content I start with. But slides that start with `itemize` or displayed equations have some extra vertical space between the frametitle and the content. Without success, I have tried adding `\vspace{-\topsep}` before `itemize` and `\vspace{-\abovedisplayskip}` before `align*`.

In the end, I would like to use the Metropolis theme, but I suspect that the problem is unrelated to the theme.

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
% \usetheme[sectionpage=none]{metropolis}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}{First frame}
    Hello, world!
  \end{frame}

  \begin{frame}{Second frame}
    % \vspace{-\topsep}
    \begin{itemize}
      \item Hello, world!
    \end{itemize}
  \end{frame}

  \begin{frame}{Third frame}
    % \vspace{-\abovedisplayskip}
    \begin{align*}
      Hello, world!
    \end{align*}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\vspace{}` is probably the way to go. The method to the madness (as per [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/172611/71332)) seems to be that displayed equations start a new paragraph (hence, `vspace{-\baselineskip}`) and then add a skip (hence, `\vspace{-\abovedisplayskip}`). As for the list, `\vspace{-\topsep}` is because there is space added to an assumed preceding paragraph. However, the logic behind `\vspace{-\itemsep}` escapes me.

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
% \usetheme[sectionpage=none]{metropolis}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}{First frame}
    Hello, world!
  \end{frame}

  \begin{frame}{Second frame}
    \vspace{-\topsep}\vspace{\itemsep}
    \begin{itemize}
      \item Hello, world!
    \end{itemize}
  \end{frame}

  \begin{frame}{Third frame}
    \vspace{-\baselineskip}\vspace{-\abovedisplayskip}
    \begin{align*}
      Hello, world!
    \end{align*}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure there is a good way to achieve this. Also, I don't know which tag or environment is responsible for this (and there might well be differences for various themes, for all I know), but I think your `\vspace{-...}` approach might be the way to go for now.

In a case like that, I usually draw a `TikZ` grid on the page (or slide) in question, and adjust my values accordingly:

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\newcommand\drawgrid{
\tikzset{strong lines/.style={black!25, very thin}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \draw[style=strong lines,step=2.5mm] 
(current page.south west) grid (current page.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}}

  \begin{frame}[t]{First frame}
    \drawgrid

    Hello, world!
  \end{frame}

  \begin{frame}{Second frame}
    \drawgrid

    \vspace{-.6ex}
    \begin{itemize}
          \item Hello, world!
    \end{itemize}
  \end{frame}

  \begin{frame}{Third frame}
    \drawgrid

    \vspace{-5.1ex}
    \begin{align*}
      Hello, world!
    \end{align*}
  \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

It is, I admit, not a very elegant solution, but it should work in a pinch. I'll have to let others figure out what causes it and how to fix it “properly”.

Comment: The `\drawgrid` command shifts the frame content down, which makes the adjustments conditional on having the grid there. I suppose that one could change the color of the grid so that it invisible...