# LYX - empty space in block

Tags: beamer, lyx, block

Hey I try to do block in LYX but I get sth like this:
[image]

How can I delete this empty space?

My code:

```
#LyX 2.3 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 544
\begin_document
\begin_header
\save_transient_properties true
\origin unavailable
\textclass beamer
\begin_preamble
\usetheme{Warsaw}
% or ...

\setbeamercovered{transparent}
% or whatever (possibly just delete it)
\end_preamble
\use_default_options false
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language english
\language_package default
\inputencoding auto
\fontencoding global
\font_roman "lmodern" "default"
\font_sans "lmss" "default"
\font_typewriter "lmtt" "default"
\font_math "auto" "auto"
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts false
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100 100
\font_tt_scale 100 100
\use_microtype false
\use_dash_ligatures false
\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command default
\index_command default
\paperfontsize default
\spacing single
\use_hyperref false
\papersize default
\use_geometry true
\use_package amsmath 2
\use_package amssymb 2
\use_package cancel 1
\use_package esint 1
\use_package mathdots 1
\use_package mathtools 1
\use_package mhchem 1
\use_package stackrel 1
\use_package stmaryrd 1
\use_package undertilde 1
\cite_engine basic
\cite_engine_type default
\biblio_style plain
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\justification true
\use_refstyle 0
\use_minted 0
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\secnumdepth 2
\tocdepth 2
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation default
\is_math_indent 0
\math_numbering_side default
\quotes_style english
\dynamic_quotes 0
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle default
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Frame
\begin_inset Argument 4
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout
Brownian Bridge
\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_deeper
\begin_layout Block
\begin_inset Argument 2
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout
Definicja
\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Block

\size footnotesize
\begin_inset Formula 
\begin{eqnarray*}
p\left(x,y,T,B,\sigma,"\text{DOWN}"\right) & = & \mathbb{P}\left(\exists t\in\left[0,T\right]:S_{t}\le D|S_{0}=x,S_{T}=y\right)\\
p\left(x,y,T,B,\sigma,"\text{UP}"\right) & = & \mathbb{P}\left(\exists t\in\left[0,T\right]:S_{t}\ge D|S_{0}=x,S_{T}=y\right)
\end{eqnarray*}

\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_deeper
\begin_layout Frame

\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.se! I can't reproduce your example. Can you please post a minimal .lyx example file and additionally the corresponding .tex code. Please read here for how to do that: https://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample

Comment: But How can I add lyx file?

Comment: please read here: https://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample#toc9

Comment: OK I add my code

Comment: Thanks, I can reproduce now. You are running into the issue here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28251/too-much-space-at-the-top-of-a-beamer-block-when-using-multilined-math-environme If you want to change the behavior globally, you can add `\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{\setlength\abovedisplayskip{0pt}}` to your preamble. Of you can use ERT to change it just for one frame.

Comment: I add this to preamble in document->settings but it still doesnt work :( Now my preamble is 
`\usetheme{Warsaw}
% or ...
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{\setlength\abovedisplayskip{0pt}}`

Comment: If you use `equation*` instead of `eqnarray*` does if make any difference?

Comment: With `equation` everything works fine, thanks :D  Of course now these two equations are not align with respect to `=` symbol and I have to do it by trial and error method  :(

Comment: @Kerni My fault. In addition to the preamble change, I needed to select all text, go to Edit > Text style > Customized and change "size" to "default". This gets rid of the space, but the text is too large. I have no idea why the "footnotesize" causes a problem. Strangely if you change the size to "smallest", there's no problem.